# Python turning screenshot code into function

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have created a screenshotting method for my code but I would like to turn said code into a function because I wanted to use it a couple times. This is the code:

```
import os

for i in range(20):

       print("")

 print("Screenshot taken.")

 for i in range(20):

        print("")

 os.system("screencapture Screenshottie.png")

 os.system('Screenshottie.png')
```

> formatting edits

Comment: what code you want inside the function ?

Comment: I wanted to basically put everything I posted above into it just so I can type a line and it activates that code whenever I need it instead of needing to type all of those lines.

Comment: Method and function is the same thing. You should also read up on _very_, _very_ basic Python, as most of them explain how functions work very on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can not understand your question completely but in python when you want to make a function you should use def like this:

```
import os


def screenshotter():

    os.system("screencapture Screenshottie.png")

    os.system('Screenshottie.png')

    return "Screenshot taken."


for i in range(20):

    print(screenshotter())

print("Done.")
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking up a basic Python introduction/tutorial, but in any case:

```
def screenshot(fname):
    print("Screenshot taken.")
    os.system("screencapture {}".format(fname))
    os.system(fname)
```